# URL Redirects using .htaccess

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, redirect

We are currently running Magento 1.9.0.1 CE for our online store.
We have a domain example.com and a subdomain in.example.com

We use in.example.com specifically for customers from India whereas everybody else is meant for example.com. We are currently using geoip database to redirect. The issues that we are facing are as follows -

1. if somebody from India opens example.com/page.html they get redirected to in.example.com instead of in.example.com/page.html
2. if somebody from USA opens in.example.com they are not getting redirected to example.com at all. same is also true for in.example.com/page.html
3. even with these redirects we want example.com/admin to not get redirected whether accessing from India or USA.

Code that I have used is as follows -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*in.mokshafashions\.com [NC]

RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:india]

RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mokshafashions.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ in.mokshafashions.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mokshafashions.com/$1$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.* – –
```

Comment: You could achieve this with nginx redirects intead of .htaccess. Check this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/380642/nginx-how-to-redirect-users-with-certain-ip-to-special-page

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an `mod_rewrite` expert, but I'll try.

To fix 1. and 2. you have to add the path and all parameters, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://in.example.com$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [L]
```

The last problem can be fixed while just avoiding the redirect, this should work like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.*
```

Comment: Greetings @Fabian,  

This doesn't work much for me. Maybe I am not writing the redirect condition wrong. Attaching below the code I am using. Kindly let me know what changes I need to make. Much appreciated.

#RewriteBase /magento/RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*in.mokshafashions\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:india]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mokshafashions.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ in.mokshafashions.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mokshafashions.com/$1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin.* –

Comment: I don't understand why the formatting is not working. use double space as well as <br/> tag.

Comment: edit your question if you want formatting. comments only allow ```

Comment: I hope it makes more sense now. edited the question itself.

Comment: still not working. This is causing fatal error. Moreover admin goes to in.mokshafashions.com